# Different results for Keras recall and custom recall

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am implementing a model for time series prediction. Given a multi-attribute input of N steps i output vectors of size 5 containing binary variables.
For example an output vector may be : [1 0 0 1 0]. This is compared against a true one.
I also have a batch size of 32.
Base on this i calculate recall as seen below:

```
def recall_m(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = tf.math.reduce_sum (K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)), axis=1)
    possible_positives = tf.math.reduce_sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)), axis=1)
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    return tf.math.reduce_mean(recall)
```

Here we have `y_true` and `y_pred` of size `(5,32)` and i calculate true positives, true negatives and recall for each sample of the batch and then average the results.
The problem is that if i use `tf.keras.metrics.Recall()` instead of this i get completely different results (for the first case (custom) i get around `0.05` and for the second `0.6`).
Am i implementing it wrong in the first case?

Comment: Are you rounding the predicted values to 0 or 1? You should avoid that.

Comment: @iohans Each true vector  [x1 x2 x3 x4 x5] is  binary so i believe they should be rounded. If not the number of true positives would be a float with decimals which i think is not the point.

Comment: Try updating the true_positives line and avoid the rounding: true_positives = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.cast(tf.math.greater_equal(y_pred, 0.5), tf.float32) * y_true, axis=1)

Comment: @iohans Still the same bahaviour. Is it possible that the built-in function makes the calculation for the whole batch concurrently and not for each instance separately and afterwards averaging?

Comment: From the recall doc: If class_id is specified, they calculate recall by considering only the entries in the batch for which class_id is in the label, and computing the fraction of them for which class_id is above the threshold and/or in the top-k predictions. (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Recall)

Comment: depends on your definition of "true positive"... if it's "true positive" if and only if the whole 0/1 vector is equal to the target one, then you can't use the naive implementation... also consider the existence of https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/RecallAtPrecision